# Azure Bot messaging endpoint does not get teamMemberRemoved event when the Bot App is removed from Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I created an Azure Bot and set the `Messaging Endpoint` to my web-app, which is not hosted on Azure.
I created a deploy package zip as a `Teams App` to be deployed on Teams and use my bot.

My messaging endpoint gets the `ConversationUpdate` events with `membersAdded` type when the customer adds my bot to Teams, and when users are added. The events are sent to the `Messaging Endpoint` configured in my bot.

When the customer deletes the App from Teams I do not get any event to the messaging endpoint.
According to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/which-event-fired-when-someone-uninstall-your-app-in-microsoft/m-p/1610299 I expected to get an event with type `teamMemberRemoved` to the bot messaging endpoint.

I need to know the Teams App was removed so I can clean up resources on my end, and indicate in my UI to the customer that the bot is no longer configured for his Teams team.

I tried adding and removing the App from my Teams account a few times but never got the expected event to the messaging endpoint.

How can I know that my App was uninstalled on a Teams team?

Comment: You should be able to get it - Could you please share the code snippet of onConversationUpdateAsync or share some for repro?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know when the App is getting added or remove you can use [`OnInstallationUpdateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler.oninstallationupdateactivityasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#microsoft-bot-builder-activityhandler-oninstallationupdateactivityasync(microsoft-bot-builder-iturncontext((microsoft-bot-schema-iinstallationupdateactivity))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)), here you will get the type `installationUpdate` and `action` as remove when it gets uninstalled.

[image]

I tried with `onConversationUpdateAsync` as well and got the request as [image]. Please confirm once if you are handling it property,

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `onConversationUpdateAsync` is for bots hosted on Azure. My bot is not hosted on Azure. My bot only gets events from Teams sent to the "Messaging Endpoint", and that endpoint never gets an `installationUpdate` event when the app is removed from Teams. I do not have an `OnInstallationUpdateAsync` implementation to share.

Comment: Can you please check this stack over flow thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69618583/how-to-check-if-bot-application-is-uninstalled-from-ms-teams